# Error finding UserKey with Google Directory Admin API

Tags: java, google-admin-sdk

I have some code to retrieve, delete, and update, and create google users. I can create the user with no problem using:

```
public void createUser(String id, String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password){

    User user = new User();

    try{


        UserName name = new UserName();
        name.setFamilyName(lastName);
        name.setGivenName(firstName);
        user.setName(name);
        user.setPassword(password);
        user.setPrimaryEmail(email);
        user.setId(id);

        System.out.println(service.users().insert(user).execute());         
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error creating user: " + e);
    }
```

I can also retrieve the userKey with:

```
System.out.println("UserKey: " + service.users().get(id).getUserKey());
```

But when I try to update or delete the user with the id, I get the following error:

```
 com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
  "domain" : "global",
  "message" : "Resource Not Found: userKey",
  "reason" : "notFound"
} ],
"message" : "Resource Not Found: userKey"
}
```

My delete method looks like:

```
public void deleteUser(String id){
    try{
        System.out.println(service.users().delete(id).execute());
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error deleting user: " + e);
    }
}
```

If I pass the delete or update methods the email address (id@domain.edu), it finds the account and works correctly, but I need to be able to pass just the id I created the account with in the insert method. Any ideas?

Comment: when you refer to "id" are you talking about the Google ID of the user (unique to all Google accounts) that Google maintains or are you talking about the local part of the user's email address (e.g. user in user@domain.com)?

Comment: It should be the local part of the email address. When I call the getUserKey method with the id (my code about halfway up) it returns the userKey as the id I set when I created the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling Directory API, you must always specify the full email address of the user or else the Google unique id of the user. It's not sufficient to simply provide the local part of the username as this does not allow Google to determine which Google Apps domain the user is associated with.

Comment: Thanks. I'll just pass in the id and tack on the "@domain.edu" before I use it.